# Tsql Select All Characters Right of Certain Character

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a varchar column containing values similar to "1.2.3 Technical Report - Study/Services, Material and Process Test Reports", and need SELECT to return "Study/Services, Material and Process Test Reports", meaning everything to the right of the hyphen and space.

This tsql...

```
select right(COLUMN, charindex(' - ', COLUMN)) from MYTABLE where PK_ID = 123;
```

Returns...
"nd Process Test Reports"

Suggestions?

Comment: use substring instead of right

Answer (score 1):

Use `substring()` :

```
select substring(col, charindex('- ', col) + 2, len(col))
from MYTABLE 
where PK_ID = 123;
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative approach, instead of returning all the characters to the "right" of the pattern, you could "remove" all the characters up to and including them

```
SELECT STUFF(Col, 1, CHARINDEX(' - ',col) +3, '') AS NewCol
FROM MYTABLE
WHERE PK_ID = 123;
```

If your column may not have the pattern `' - '` then you could do:

```
STUFF(Col, 1, ISNULL(NULLIF(CHARINDEX(' - ',col),0) +3),0), '')
```